# how to assign a value to a control inside a nested gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have parent gridview called 'gvParentGrid' and within I have nested gridiview called 'gvChildGrid'.  I have created a row databound event in the parent gridview - gvParentGrid .

I trying to assign label11 to my sql query output.  In the code below, I attempted to assign rDate to label11 variable, but it keeps throwing a -- **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            con.Open();
            GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid");

            Label lblorderID = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label2");

            Label lblRead = (Label)gv.FindControl("Label11");

            string userID = lblorderID.Text;

            string cmdstr = "select top 2 [rUID], count([rDATE]) as 'articles read' from ArticlesRead where [rUID] = @ID group by [rUID] order by count([rDATE]) desc";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Line below causing the object reference error.
                ***lblRead.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();***
            }

            con.Close();

            gv.DataSource = ds;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
```

Here is the client-side template for further reference:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvParentGrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="uID"  Width="300" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvUserInfo_RowDataBound">
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label><br />
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uID") %>' >   </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="uID">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Articles Read">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Any further advice would be very much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You should not be executing a database query for every single row in your set of data.  You should be executing one query once (this probably means just doing a join), build up one complete set of results that will be used to bind the outer gridview and all inner gridviews, and then bind everything all at once.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise against using the RowDataBind event.  Do *all* of the binding in markup instead.  It will not only encourage you to follow the advice of my previous comment, but it's easier and simply allows you to take advantage of all of the tools offered to you.  There's not much point in using a GridView if you don't actually utilize the databinding features of it.

Comment: The `lblRead` Label is NULL and in your `if` condition you're not validating if the Label is different of NULL (hence, the _Exception_), and in your code sample you're missing more code, like the `Columns` tags inside `GridView`. Please, update your question.